# How to call login activity in fragment Navigation Bottom Bar

Tags: android, session, authentication, android-fragmentactivity, android-sharedpreferences

i make an application which is have 3 bottom navigation bar

this my main activity java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener
            = new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.navigation_home:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new LoginFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_dashboard:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new DashboardFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
                case R.id.navigation_notifications:
                    transaction.replace(R.id.content, new NotificationsFragment()).commit();
                    return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
        navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.content, new LoginFragment()).commit();
    }

}
```

and for the xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.network.poeja.diskusiku.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and then i create a LoginFragment to show first navigation

```
public class LoginFragment extends Fragment {

    Button btn_logout;
    TextView txt_id, txt_username;
    String id, username;
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;

    public static final String TAG_ID = "id";
    public static final String TAG_USERNAME = "username";

    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";

    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private String mParam1;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

    public LoginFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    /**
     * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
     * this fragment using the provided parameters.
     *
     * @param param1 Parameter 1.
     * @param param2 Parameter 2.
     * @return A new instance of fragment LoginFragment.
     */
    // TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
    public static LoginFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        LoginFragment fragment = new LoginFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        txt_id = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txt_id);
        txt_username = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        btn_logout = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);

        sharedpreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(Login.my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        id = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_ID);
        username = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra(TAG_USERNAME);

        txt_id.setText("ID : " + id);
        txt_username.setText("USERNAME : " + username);

        btn_logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // update login session ke FALSE dan mengosongkan nilai id dan username
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(Login.session_status, false);
                editor.putString(TAG_ID, null);
                editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, null);
                editor.commit();

                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), Login.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
            mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);


        return view;
    }

    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }

    /**
     * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
     * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
     * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
     * activity.
     * <p>
     * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
     * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
     * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
     */
    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }

}
```

here is the xml of LoginFragment

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.network.poeja.diskusiku.LoginFragment">

<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="www.dedykuncoro.com"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#448AFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="ID"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:text="Username"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:background="#f5f5f5"
        android:text="Logout"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/title_home" />
</LinearLayout>
```

and i make the login java to check session

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    Button btn_register, btn_login;
    EditText txt_username, txt_password;
    Intent intent;

    int success;
    ConnectivityManager conMgr;

    private String url = Server.URL + "login.php";

    private static final String TAG = Login.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_MESSAGE = "message";

    public final static String TAG_USERNAME = "username";
    public final static String TAG_ID = "id";

    String tag_json_obj = "json_obj_req";

    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;
    Boolean session = false;
    String id, username;
    public static final String my_shared_preferences = "my_shared_preferences";
    public static final String session_status = "session_status";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);

        conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        {
            if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                    && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }

        btn_login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
        btn_register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
        txt_username = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        txt_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txt_password);

        // Chek session login if TRUE then directly open LoginFragment
        sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(my_shared_preferences, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        session = sharedpreferences.getBoolean(session_status, false);
        id = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_ID, null);
        username = sharedpreferences.getString(TAG_USERNAME, null);

        if (session) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, LoginFragment.class);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
            intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }


        btn_login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String username = txt_username.getText().toString();
                String password = txt_password.getText().toString();

                // check if field is empty
                if (username.trim().length() > 0 && password.trim().length() > 0) {
                    if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                            && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
                        checkLogin(username, password);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } else {
                    // Prompt user to enter credentials
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() ,"Kolom tidak boleh kosong", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                intent = new Intent(Login.this, Register.class);
                finish();
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

    }

    private void checkLogin(final String username, final String password) {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setMessage("Logging in ...");
        showDialog();

        StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Response: " + response.toString());
                hideDialog();

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                    success = jObj.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                    // Check for error node in json
                    if (success == 1) {
                        String username = jObj.getString(TAG_USERNAME);
                        String id = jObj.getString(TAG_ID);

                        Log.e("Successfully Login!", jObj.toString());

                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        // Save login to session
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
                        editor.putBoolean(session_status, true);
                        editor.putString(TAG_ID, id);
                        editor.putString(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        editor.commit();

                        // Call main activity
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, LoginFragment.class);
                        intent.putExtra(TAG_ID, id);
                        intent.putExtra(TAG_USERNAME, username);
                        finish();
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                                jObj.getString(TAG_MESSAGE), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                hideDialog();

            }
        }) {

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                // Posting parameters to login url
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("username", username);
                params.put("password", password);

                return params;
            }

        };

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_json_obj);
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        if (!pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.show();
    }

    private void hideDialog() {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

and here the login xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.network.poeja.diskusiku.LoginFragment">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logo"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text="www.dedykuncoro.com"
        android:textSize="18dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/View1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#448AFF" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dip"
        android:text="WELCOME, LOGIN BELOW"
        android:textSize="16dip" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:password="true"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="Login"
        android:background="#448AFF"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_register"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="#00555555"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

but i still face some error, when i start to run the application, it's **force close** and i don't know how to fix it

what i want is, when user click on home navigation it will check if he login or not,

if login, he will show his id and username
if no, then show the login page

anyone please help, if you want full code of the code please contact me i will sent it to you

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is coming from the login fragment. You should not do a **findViewById** from the **onCreate** but instead from the **onCreateView**.

Fragments life cycle is a little bit different from the activities one. Simply move the ui initialization to the **onCreateView** method and you should be good to go :)